# Creating relationship class for many to many relationship

Tags: arcmap, relationship-class, relates, parcel

In Arcmap 10.7, I am trying to set up a relationship class that will link parcels to owners. The end goal is to be able select a parcel and see the owner, or multiple owners associated with it.

Some parcels have multiple owners and some owners have multiple parcels. I assume this means I need a many to many relationship. I have a feature class of parcel polygons, and a stand alone table with owner information. They are both in the same geodatabase. I have tried using parcels as origin, and also using owners table as origin. I am using a simple relationship both ways. I choose no message propagation since I am unsure what does (how edits are passed along?).

I can never get any records to show up in the related tables. I believe the keys I am using to link them are valid, both tables have many overlapping values. Is there a reason I can't get any related records to show up? This was asked before in [Records in related table do not appear when using the 'Related Tables' button in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23899/records-in-related-table-do-not-appear-when-using-the-related-tables-button-in) post but was never answered.

I saw other posts describing using overlapping polygons to solve the multiple owners problem, but that isn't what I would like to do if possible. Would like to just have all the owners associated to the one parcel shape in the feature class.

Comment: No, not many to many, one to many relation. At any one time you are only interested in *one* parcel that can have *multiple* owners; another parcel may point to an owner that owns another parcel but that does not mean many to many. Please explain more about what table field the parcels have to link to the owner table and the primary key in the owner table.

Comment: Ok, I will have to try One to Many. I am using a Tax Schedule number as the key, so it is a field which is unique to an owner. The context of this question is for tax assessing purposes.

Comment: How is (are) these numbers associated with your parcels? In a one-to-many relate a single number or identity would be present in one or more rows in your table. If you have multiple Tax Schedule numbers in one text field with some sort of delimiter you're not going to be able to link the tables without doing some processing first; to give guidance on how to setup both tables for a relate I would need to see some examples from both tables - feel free to redact any personal information and/or create dummy rows with numbers that look like Tax Schedule numbers if that too is personal information.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I previously had all the tax schedule numbers in one column per one parcel row, now I have created a table where the parcel numbers are duplicated, in order for one tax schedule record to associate with one parcel record. I believe this is the best way to do the one to many correct? Now I should be able to link my parcels to this new table, to display multiple owners, while not duplicating the geometry of parcels with multiple owners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a many to many relationship you will need 3 table, the first with the parcel info, the second with the owner info, the third one list all parcel ID / owner ID relation.

This third table need only two column one with the parcel ID, the other with the owner ID.

[This page from ESRI](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000004999) has a short explanation on how to set it up. [More info on the third table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/populating-an-attributed-relationship-class-table-.htm) could be find here.

Comment: Thanks. The 3rd table was throwing me for a loop. Appreciate it.