# How to handle many to many relationship?

Tags: qgis, many-to-many

I'm dealing with land development, where a land could have multiple investments and the other way around.

### What I've got:

1. A shapfile with all land informations, each labels an unique id.

| LAND_ID | AREA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1000 |

2. A csv file that shows how many lands involved in each cases.

| CASE_ID | LANDS | INVESTOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 1, 2 | John |
| A02 | 2 | Tom |
| A03 | 2 | Dave |

#### Solving attempts 01

First I tried to split LANDS and gave each a different rows:

| CASE_ID | LANDS | INVESTOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 1 | John |
| A01 | 2 | John |
| A02 | 2 | Tom |
| A03 | 2 | Dave |

and join by LANDS, which...failed since QGIS seems to overwrite the same element. The output would erase row 2 & 3.

#### Solving attempts 02

I wrote some code outside of QGIS to make the second list looks something like this.

| LAND_ID | AREA | CASES | INVESTORS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | A01 | John |
| 2 | 1000 | 1.A01 ; 2.A02 ; 3.A03 | 1.John ; 2.Tom ; 3.Dave |

So that I could join the list onto the shapfile within QGIS, yet the table becomes hard to read. I wonder if it's possible to have a 'subset-like' way to show how many investments are going on when inspecting the land? I mean by clicking on, for instance land 2, I could shows 3 tables that's related to it (in this case all of them).

Comment: A related question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323624/creating-relationship-class-for-many-to-many-relationship/323668#323668 (the answer link to an ESRI page but the concept are the same)